# PHPMailer not working with SMTP Server

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send an email from a contact form through an SMTP Server. When I click "Submit" The page goes blank and there's a hashtag symbol in the url, and when I try it on a server the page says in plain html text "there has been a server error" or something along the lines of that. I've probably gone through over 20 stack overflow threads with phpmailer and I can't figure it out. I removed all of the $mail code including the $mail = new PHPMailer(); text and it would work and send me to the homepage but it wouldn't send the email obviously so that's where the error is.

The PHP and HTML are on one page just in case anyone is wondering.

php

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);


    if ($firstname == "" OR $lastname == "" OR $email == "" OR $number == "" OR $message == "") {
        echo "You must specify a value for name, email address, and message.";
        exit;
    }

    foreach( $_POST as $value ){
        if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
            echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";    
            exit;
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
        echo "Your form submission has an error.";
        exit;
    }

    require_once("inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.postmarkapp.com";
    $mail->Port = 2525;
    $mail->Username = "**********";
    $mail->Password = "**********";

    $mail->SetFrom('site-admin@example.com', 'Web App');
    $mail->Subject = "Contact Form Submission | " . $name;

    $email_body = "";
    $email_body = $email_body . "First Name: " . $firstname . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Last Name: " . $lastname . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Number: " . $number . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message;

    if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Message sent!";
    } else {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

HTML

```
        <div class="contact-form">

                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="number">Your Phone Number</label>
                        <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" type="message"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="message">
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
                    </p>
                    <p class="addressvalidation">
                        <label for="address">Address</label>
                        <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
                        <p class="displaytext">Please leave this field blank.</p>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change:

```
<?php
```

into

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

to have displayed all errors.

Submit form and you should have displayed your error.

If it won't help make sure that in:

```
require_once("inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

ould also 
you use correct path (on Linux paths are case sensitive).

You could also comment line:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

for testing to have displayed any info. Now you display error, but right after it you try to make redirection. Also before redirection you shouldn't display anything otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So at first I got an error saying that I was missing phpauto loader or something, so I put that in the phpmailer file which helped. Now I get an error that says "Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address." even when I put in a valid email address in the email address field.

Comment: Okay I fixed that error and some other errors. Now when I put the page on a server and run the form and click submit, the page goes blank with this one error message "Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b899/ipg.cakebygiageneacom/inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1177" I went to that line and there's this         public function getSMTPInstance()
        {
            if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
                $this->smtp = new SMTP;
            }
            return $this->smtp;
        }

Comment: Ohhh there's an actual SMTP class that I forgot to include.... Fixed that, and now when I run the form the page runs for a few seconds and then I get "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed." So I'm guessing the SMPT authentication isn't working?

Comment: @EliotWinchell Yes, it seems you provide incorrect data. Make sure that host, port, username and password are valid

Comment: You don't need to load the SMTP class yourself - you should be using the PHPMailer autoloader: `require 'inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`
Also, while you're creating a message body in `$email_body`, you're never giving it to PHPMailer, so add this: `$mail->Body = $email_body;`, or `$mail->msgHTML($email_body);`. If you have an auth failure, it will say so; the error you have is more likely to be wrong hostname, wrong port, or a local DNS or firewall failure.